# Assigning different variables to different lines of a text file in Python

Tags: python, variables

There were some other questions that were similar but none of them answered my question. I need a simple way to assign a different variable to each line, so I can use it later on.

Please keep it simple, it's for my controlled assessment and I need to remember all of it.

Comment: Any other demands?  Do you have a solution that is too complex, or are you just trying to get others dot do your work for you?

Comment: What if the text file had a million lines?  Are you going to type out a million variable names?   On a related subject: are you familiar with the `list` type?

Comment: It's "for your controlled assessment"? Do you mean you are trying to cheat on a test?

Comment: No, cheating is taking in work to the classroom. We are free to research or ask questions in our free time. Anyways, there are only 2 lines that I need to load into a program and both are numbers. Also, no, I am not familiar with the list.

Answer (score 4):

No, you absolutely do *not* want to do this. There is never any reason to be assigning an unknown number of variables.

You assign a *single* variable, a list, with each element equal to a line:

```
f = open('myfile.text')
contents = f.readlines()
```

although most likely, since that will include the newline character at the end of the line, you want to strip it off first:

```
contents = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Comment: For my program, that is exactly what I need as I'm loading 2 numbers from a different program.